# trouble compreending how to stop the loop if true

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

it's my first post here and I'm trying to do a freecodecamp exercise.

Here's my code:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let newArr = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let arrNew = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let test = newArr.split(' ');
  let newTest = arrNew.split(' ');

  for (let i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j < newTest.length; j++) {
      if (newTest[j] === test[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

The exercise is "Mutations" and I need to return true if the 1st string on the array has all the letters from the 2nd.
I'm trying to understand how to stop the loop when the if statement is true and save it.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly.

Comment: Can you explain with some examples. One that must return true and another that must return false. Thanks

Comment: "return" stops the loop. If it keeps running, that means newTest[j] === test[i] return always false, and that block is never executed.

Comment: @FS-GSW Sure, sorry. Here are the results wanted: 

mutation(["hello", "hey"]) should return false.

mutation(["hello", "Hello"]) should return true.

Comment: Okay and `mutation( ["hello", "hellooooo"] )` should return true or false ?

Comment: @FS-GSW It should return true because "mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]) should return true." So it has to have all the letters

Comment: Just a suggestion for clarity of vision particularly here since you're trying to find out what's going on in an algorithm, please name your variables right. newArr = arr[0].toLowerCase();  and let test = newArr.split(' '); should just be "let comparedString1= arr[0].toLowerCase()newArr.split(' ');"

Comment: @wiwi Yeah, I was thinking about that. I will have that in mind in the future also, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to utilize loops like in your example code here is a very verbose way to do so:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let hasAllLetters = true;
  let stringToCompare = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let referenceString = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let hasCurrentLetter;
  
  for (let i=0; i < referenceString.length; i++) {
    hasCurrentLetter = false;
    
    for (let j=0; j < stringToCompare.length; j++) {
        
      if (referenceString[i] === stringToCompare[j]) {
        hasCurrentLetter = true;
        
        // break from the second loop as soon as the condition is satisfied
        break;
      }
    }
        
    if(!hasCurrentLetter){
      hasAllLetters = false;
      // as soon as there is at least one letter which does not exist from the reference string
      // break from the second loop and exit yielding the result false
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return hasAllLetters;
}

let res;

res = mutation(["hello", "goll"]);
console.log("res: ", res); // false

res = mutation(["hello", "olhh"]);
console.log("res: ", res); // true
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I'm trying to understand how the scoping you did works. I guess it's the next step I have to work on. Thank you!

Comment: @Shoqolate if it answers your question please tag it as accepted then ;)

Comment: And if you have further questions on the code, dont hesitate

Answer (score 1):

### For your question

`return` will exit the function and therefore will exit the loop. 
 From that we know that if your function returns *false* the condition `newTest[j] === test[i]` was never verified.

### Hint for the exercise

You can suppose that the first word has all the letters from the second, iterate just like you're doing right now and check if you find a counter-example !

Answer (score 1):

The following code should help you.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
    let newArr = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    let arrNew = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  
    for (let i=0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (arrNew.indexOf(newArr[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

There is no need to use arrays. in JS, strings work like arrays and we can use a "for" loop.

Comment: Shoqolate : this code is much better... You can try this.